# Unable to do a simple cycle and list interaction to replace values on an array (list of lists)

Tags: python, arrays

Basically what I want is to switch every number above, below, to the left and to the right of my number 1, in each iteration. Something like this (consider # the number one, and '  ' the number 0:

```
---------------------
|   |   |   |   |   |
---------------------
|   |   |   |   |   |
---------------------
|   |   | # |   |   |
---------------------
|   |   |   |   |   |
---------------------
|   |   |   |   |   |
---------------------


---------------------
|   |   |   |   |   |
---------------------
|   |   | # |   |   |
---------------------
|   | # | # | # |   |
---------------------
|   |   | # |   |   |
---------------------
|   |   |   |   |   |
---------------------

---------------------
|   |   | # |   |   |
---------------------
|   | # | # | # |   |
---------------------
| # | # | # | # | # |
---------------------
|   | # | # | # |   |
---------------------
|   |   | # |   |   |
---------------------

---------------------
|   | # | # | # |   |
---------------------
| # | # | # | # | # |
---------------------
| # | # | # | # | # |
---------------------
| # | # | # | # | # |
---------------------
|   | # | # | # |   |
---------------------

---------------------
| # | # | # | # | # |
---------------------
| # | # | # | # | # |
---------------------
| # | # | # | # | # |
---------------------
| # | # | # | # | # |
---------------------
| # | # | # | # |   |
---------------------
```

Everything goes well until I cant switch the number zero in the position (4,4).
Cant seem to find what is wrong, I know the code is sloppy, but what am I doing that is stopping the last number from changing?

```
linhas=5

matrix =[]
for i in range(linhas):
    linha1=[]
    for j in range(colunas):
        linha1.append(0)
    matrix.append(linha1)
pl=[]
cont=0
matrix[2][2]=1
while len(pl)!= colunas*linhas:
    cont+=1
    pl=[]
    print(matrix)
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        for j in range(len(matrix[i])):
            if matrix[i][j]==1:
                lista=[i,j]
                pl.append(lista)

    for l in range(len(pl)):
        i= pl[l][0]
        j= pl[l][1]

        #this is wrong, now corrected below
        #if (j>=0 and j+1<=len(matrix)-1) and (i>=0 and i+1<=len(matrix)-1):
            #if matrix[i][j-1]==0:
                #matrix[i][j-1]=1
            #if matrix[i][j+1]==0:
                #matrix[i][j+1]=1
            #if matrix[i-1][j]==0:
                #matrix[i-1][j]=1
            #if matrix[i+1][j]==0:
                #matrix[i+1][j]=1
correction, remove # text and substitute with this:

    if j-1>=0:
        if matrix[i][j-1]==0:
            matrix[i][j-1]=1
    if j+1<colunas:
        if matrix[i][j+1]==0:
            matrix[i][j+1]=1
    if i-1>=0:
        if matrix[i-1][j]==0:
            matrix[i-1][j]=1
    if i+1<linhas:
        if matrix[i+1][j]==0:
            matrix[i+1][j]=1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`j` is a column index. `i` is a row index.

`j >= 0` is true for all valid column indices. (But note that `matrix[i][j-1]` could be `matrix[i][-1]` if `j` is 0. That may not be what you want to happen...)

`j+1<=len(matrix)-1` means the column has to be on less than the maximum possible column index.

So `(j>=0 and j+1<=len(matrix)-1)` means `j` can not be in the last column.

Similarly, `(i>=0 and i+1<=len(matrix)-1)` means `i` can to be in the last row.

To flip `matrix[4][4]` from 0 to 1, `(i,j)` must be either (4,3) or (3,4) but both of these tuples are rejected by the if-condition since (4,3) is in the last row and (3,4) is in the last column.

Comment: Yeah I thought that the if condition to keep it in bounds would be the problem, any advice on a similar condition?

Comment: Break it into different conditions for each of the 4  sub-if-statements.

Comment: Been trying for 2 hours and cant seem to find a proper condition to force the index to stay in bounds and still include the (4,4). Any sugestion?

Comment: Nevermind, reached a solution just now. Thanks for your answer, it really helped me.